# udp socket programming file transfer

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, while-loop, memset

Server Side Code.........

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

#define BUFLEN 503
#define PORT 8885

void die(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;

    int s, i,j, slen = sizeof(si_other) , recv_len;
    char buf[BUFLEN];

    if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        die("socket");
    }

    memset((char *) &si_me, '1', sizeof(si_me));
    //printf("%d",si_me);

    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = PORT;
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if( bind(s , (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me) ) == -1)
    {
        die("bind");
    }
    //memset(buf,0,503);
    char fname[20];
    FILE *fp;
    recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, 20, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen);

    char fna[100];
    memset(buf,0,503);

    recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, 20, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen);

    strcpy(fna,buf);
    //printf("%c\n",fna);
    int len= strlen(fna);
    printf("%d",len);

    unsigned long mm = atoi(buf);
    //printf("mm value: %ld\n",mm);

    fp=fopen(fna,"wb");
    int itr=1;
    memset(buf,0,503);
    while(itr*503<mm)
    {
        if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, 503, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&si_other,          &slen)) == -1)
        {
            die("recvfrom()");
        }
        fwrite(buf,503, 1, fp);
        memset(buf,0,503);
        //printf("Loop no: %d",i)
        //for(i=0;i<=itr;i++);

        itr++;
    }

    //printf("Loop no: %d\n",i);
    printf("%d",(mm%503));
    recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, (mm%503), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen);

    fwrite(buf,(mm%503), 1, fp);
    memset(buf,0,503);
    fclose(fp);
    close(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Client Side Code........

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"
#define BUFLEN 503
#define PORT 8885

void die(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}
unsigned long fsize(char* file)
{
    //String bbb=file;
    FILE * f = fopen(file, "r");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    unsigned long len = (unsigned long)ftell(f);
    printf("Total size: %d \n",len);
    fclose(f);
    return len;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int s, i, slen=sizeof(si_other);
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    char message[BUFLEN];

    if ( (s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        die("socket");
    }

    memset((char *) &si_other, '1', sizeof(si_other));
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = PORT;
    //printf("Htons= %d \n",htons(PORT));

    if (inet_aton(SERVER , &si_other.sin_addr) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //memset(message,0,503);
    char fname[20];
    printf("Enter Filename with extension: ");
    scanf("%s",&fname);
    sendto(s, fname, 20 , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen);

    memset(message,0,503);

    unsigned long siz = fsize(fname);
    printf("siz: %ld\n",siz);

    char str[10];
    sprintf(str, "%d", siz);
    int send1=sendto(s, str, 20 , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen);
    printf("value of send1= %d",send1);

    FILE *f;

    f=fopen(fname,"rb");
    memset(message,0,503);
    fread(message, 503,1,f);

    int itr =1;
    while(itr*503<siz){

        if (sendto(s, message, 503 , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen)==-1)
        {
            die("sendto()");
        }
        memset(message,0,503);
        fread(message, 503,1,f);
        itr++;
    }
    fread(message, (siz % 503),1,f);
    int send2=sendto(s, message, (siz % 503) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen);
    printf("\n value of send 2= %d",send2);

    memset(message,0,503);
    fclose(f);
    close(s);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the code for file transfer like images, videos, text files in UDP socket programming.(From Client Side To Server Side folder).

Can anyone explain to me why the `WHILE` loop is being used on both the sides, What is its purpose?
Also, one problem is using this program the file is sent properly from client to server but after reaching the server side the filename is being changed.

```
unsigned long len = (unsigned long)ftell(f);
    printf("Total size: %d \n",len);
```

After testing I found out that the changed file name on the server side is set to the current position of the file pointer that is in `len` variable in client side.(value of `len` is same as variable `mm` in server side and variable '`siz`' on client side.

for example:

If I send "Wallpaper.png" from server side it will reach the server side and the file is saved by the name "164101". But the image is displayed properly.

AND WHY IS memset USED SO MANY TIMES ?? WHAT IS ITS ACTUAL USE ??

Comment: You should edit your question to make it clearer. If I understand you correctly, you're asking "Why does the file name of an object sent from the client to the server get changed on the server?"

Comment: on the server side you let the server choose randomly a name for the files that he receives, you can set them yourself

Comment: Given `#define PORT 8885`, the code `si_other.sin_port = PORT;` is wrong.  The port must be in network byte order, so the code should be `si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);`  Also, the code as posted doesn't do *any* error checking.

Comment: YES. Thats exactly what I'm asking @DanielLane

Comment: OK. But why is the server side always choosing the file name that is also the position of file pointer ??(or to be more specific it sets the name as the position where file pointer ends) . Can you help me how to set the file name on our own ?? @SPSP

Comment: The way to get around this problem is for everyone to put aside their differences and agree that Motorola and IBM had it right, and Intel did it the weird way, and so we all convert our byte orderings to "big-endian" before sending them out. Since Intel is a "little-endian" machine, it's far more politically correct to call our preferred byte ordering "Network Byte Order". So these functions convert from your native byte order to network byte order and back again.(I had done it exactly the same. But what I understood is you only need it do when working on different machines.Right? @AndrewHenle

Comment: `fp=fopen('your filename',"wb");` but if you don't know the file name the client should send it first, the server receive the name of file then you receive the file itself

Comment: 'AND WHY IS memset USED SO MANY TIMES ?' - why not ask the actual author of this code?

Comment: @MartinJames Is there no need for so much memset() ?? Please Help..

Answer (score 1):

Your client and server speak the same file transfer protocol, defined as follows :

- first 20 bytes contain the file name
- 20 bytes contain the file length
- actual bytes are sent and received by chunks of 503 bytes
- final chunk (lower than 503 bytes) is fetched at the end

On the server side, you're messing with variables that should store the file name `fname` and the one that should store the file length `fna`. You should probably rename the latter to `flen` like in the following snippet :

```
...
char fname[20]; // variable to store file name
FILE *fp;
recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, 20, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen);
strcpy(fname, buf); // got 20 bytes in buf, copy to fname : this is the file  name 
printf("File name : %s\n", fname);

char flen[20];
memset(buf,0,503); // reset NULL bytes to buf

recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, 20, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen);
strcpy(flen, buf); // got 20 bytes, copy to flen : this is the file length (as a string)
printf("Length as string : %s\n", flen);
printf("Length as integer : %d\n", atoi(flen));

unsigned long mm = atoi(buf); // convert file length as a string to an integer variable
printf("mm value: %ld\n",mm);

fp=fopen(fname,"wb"); // use the proper variable as the file name
int itr=1;
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to read that it worked. Happy journey in learning socket programming in C, I enjoy it much! Please do not forget to accept the answer if you think it should be accepted :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop is used to split the file into smaller chunks which fit into UDP datagrams, which have a limited size.  Unlike TCP, UDP does not deal with such details, so you have to implement all of that on your own.

Eventually, you will also have to implement timeouts and retransmits, duplicate datagram detection, and probably some form of congestion control.  Writing a good file transport protocol which beats a TCP-based solution on top of UDP is quite hard.

Comment: That helped. Can you explain a bit more on this ?? @Florian